# have the same height for a select and input in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/GurmR/19/

On IE7 (as you can see) the height of the input is not a real `height:18px` (there is a sort of padding/margin?).

They have more height than select box. How can I adjust them?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML structure is wrong , the "`input`" element should be inside  of the `<tr><td>`.

[Try This one](http://jsfiddle.net/corotchi/GurmR/28/)

Comment: but the input is "inside the <tr><td> input </td></tr>?!?!?

Comment: nu, hidden one, is just in <tr> not on <td>, in my update it is


http://jsfiddle.net/corotchi/GurmR/28/

Comment: Sorry, put old url, check the new jsFiddle link

Comment: Ah ok! But I didnt mean that height. I mean the hight between input and select! Is different. I'd like to have the same height for select, input and submit button. It change from browser to browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of .trackOn `height: 26px;` will fix it. For some reason IE7 or IE in quirks mode interprets this height value while other browsers do not.

```
.trackOn
{
    width:710px; height:0px;
}
```

Comment: It doesnt resolve my problem... I need that space for have a height of the cell. And it works nice...why remove it?

Comment: You mean to tell me that http://jsfiddle.net/GurmR/31/ does not fix your height/margin/padding issue in IE7? Then I am confused what your problem is I'm sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at jquery browser detect

You can use this code to detect if the browser is IE and then you can change the height using also jquery

```
if($.browser.msie)
{
   $(.yourobjecthere).css('height','100') //use the value you find to fit best with ie
}
```